# PHP - HTML Select Menu - Include Value outside of Array

Tags: php, html, arrays

I'm creating a simple HTML Select Menu using PHP from an array as follows:

```
$output = '';

foreach($symptoms as $symptom) {

    $symptom = htmlspecialchars($symptom);
    if ($symptom == $record->getField('PatientSymptom')) {
      $output = "<option value='".$symptom."' selected='selected' >$symptom</option>";  
    } else {
      $output = "<option value='".$symptom."'>$symptom</option>";  
    }
    echo $output;
}
```

This creates the HTML select menu from the `$symptoms` array successfully, but the original value stored in the input field that I'm displaying might not be part of the `$symptoms` array. I need to add this to the select menu in this case but not sure the best way to go about this.

I'm storing the original value in a variable: `$patientSymptom`

What's the best way to check if `$patientSymptom` isn't in the `$symptoms` array and add that to the select menu I'm creating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)** function:

> in_array — Checks if a value exists in an array

---

Check if element exists in array right before the loop and add it if necessary:

```
$output = '';
if (!in_array($patientSymptom, $symptoms)) {
   $symptoms[] = $patientSymptom; // add symptom to end of the array
}
foreach($symptoms as $symptom) {
// ...
```